# Getting error while importing data from CSV to HDFS in springXD

Tags: spring-xd

We are trying to import data from CSV to HDFS in SpringXD(release 1.3.1). We are using Hortonworks for big data environment. We are trying to use commands as given in springxd doc like:

```
xd:> job create myjob --definition "filepollhdfs --names=forename,surname,address" --deploy

xd:> stream create csvStream --definition "file --mode=ref --dir=/mycsvdir --pattern=*.csv > queue:job:myjob" --deploy

But deployment of job getting failed and getting error like:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hadoopFs' defined in file [/Users/nxjain/Documents/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE/xd/modules/job/filepollhdfs/config/filepollhdfs.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1229)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getDefaultUri(FileSystem.java:178)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
```

Thus we are not able to import data from CSV to hdfs on Hortonwork environment through SpringXD. Is there any other wayout of this problem.

Comment: That's a strange error and doesn't seem to be directly Spring XD related. I wonder if there is something in your Hadoop configuration that causes this. Spring XD is just instantiating a Hadoop `Configuration` based on what is specified in `config/servers.yml` or `config/hadoop-site.xml`

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your quick reply. We have done following entries in config/server.xml file like: spring:
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://172.16.128.128:8020 <http://172.16.128.128:8020> 
    resourceManagerHost: 172.16.128.128
    resourceManagerPort: 8050
               we have successfully created streams for time|HDFS and its working fine but if we creates a job as mentioned in the above query, its deployment fails and giving error. So, is there anything more that needs  to be done for jobs in springxd with Hortonworks

Comment: This is strange, the job doesn't really use anything special. Do you have anything in `config/hadoop.properties`?